# Type Mismatch 13 Error when deleting from a merged cell - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I having an error when I press delete button over a merged cell (Type Mismatch 13), however,
this error only shows when the cell is merged, otherwise, no error is raised and I cannot understand why, please follow down the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target = Range("AG3") Then

    If Target.Value = 5 Then
        Sheets("Sheet6").CommandButton6.Visible = False

    Else
         Sheets("Sheet6").CommandButton6.Visible = True

End If
End If

On Error Resume Next
     Sheets("Sheet6").CommandButton6.Visible = False
On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

What is missing?

The cell `AG3` has a number that varies from 0 to 5

Comment: Where are the merged cells located? Is the delete button `CommandButton6`? Is this code in the sheet module of the worksheet with the tab name `Sheet6`? Which line of code throws the error (is highlighted)? What is the purpose of the `On Error...` block of code? Why do you think that this *"The cell AG3 has a number that varies from 0 to 5"* is relevant?

Comment: The code works like this: the button (Button6) only works when the cell `AG3` has the number 5 on it, when the number is below 5, it means the user didnt have complete all 5 steps, therefore, the button does not work (that is the purpose of the `On Error`). Regarding the delete, is when I press the delete button from my keybord at any cell that is merged, it raise the error that I mentioned before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you *delete* a value from a merged cell, `Target` gets the whole range, rather than just the first cell.  This behavior is different from when you add a value to a merged cell (in which case only the first cell from the merge area gets passed in).

For example - if I merge `D2:D8` on a worksheet with this event handler:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Debug.Print Target.Address, TypeName(Target.Value)
End Sub
```

Entering "Test" into the merged cell gives me:

```
$D$2          String
```

and deleting that value gives me:

```
$D$2:$D$8             Variant()
```

I only just learned that.

So consider looking at `Target.Cells(1)` instead of `Target` (depending on your exact use case)

Comment: Very interesting to understand how it works, thank you

Answer (score 2):

### A Worksheet Change: Show Command Button

- `Target` can be any number of cells. Therefore it is best to get the intersection of it and the desired cell and if they were intersecting, continue with this intersection (actually the desired cell).

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim iCell As Range: Set iCell = Intersect(Range("AG3"), Target)
    If iCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    If iCell.Value = 5 Then
        Sheets("Sheet6").CommandButton6.Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet6").CommandButton6.Visible = False
    End If
 
End Sub
```